# How to find the intersection coordinate with circle and line equation?

Tags: geometry, circles

https://i.stack.imgur.com/krUqK.png

Example we have one line and one circle above,
and its equation are:

**Circle**: $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$

**Line**: $y = m(x-x_1) + y_1$

How do we find the intersection coordinate?

Comment: Substitute your equation for $y$ (from the line) into the equation of the circle, multiply everything out, and solve the quadratic equation to get $x$. Use the equation of the line to get a $y$ for each $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, why not bash here? Solve the equations in terms of $x,$ as follows:

**Given:**
$$(x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} = r^{2}$$
$$y = m\left(x - x_{1}\right) + y_{1}$$

**With substitution:**
$$(x - a)^{2} + \left(m\left(x - x_{1}\right) + \left(y_{1} - b\right)\right)^{2} = r^{2}$$
$$\left(x^{2} - 2ax + a^{2}\right) + m^{2}\left(x^{2} - 2x_{1}x + x_{1}^{2}\right) + 2m\left(x - x_{1}\right)\left(y_{1} - b\right) + \left(y_{1}^{2} - 2by_{1} + b^{2}\right) = r^{2}.$$

I leave you to use the **quadratic equation** on $x$ and finish the problem. Note that sometimes, there will be no solution.

Comment: The distance between the circle centre and the intersection point is:
$$D=\left|\frac{\sqrt{-4(m^2+1)((-mx_1+y_1-b_1)^2+a_1^2-c^2)+(2m(-mx_1+y_1-b_1)-2a_1)^2}-2m(-mx_1+y_1-b_1)+2a_1)}{2m^2+2}\right|$$ Bravo sir, thank you :)

Comment: No problem! When in doubt, try bashing the problem ;)